# spring sts crashed on Junit run

Tags: spring, junit, jvm, spring-tool-suite

I found recently my sts will crash every time when I try to run the project as junit applicaiton.

the error message I check in the workspace log is:

```
!ENTRY org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.metadata 4 2 2015-05-19 16:29:48.745
!MESSAGE Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.metadata".
!STACK 0
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: org.springframework.asm.Type
at java.util.AbstractCollection.toArray(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.java.annotation.AnnotationMemberVisitor$1.visitEnd(AnnotationMemberVisitor.java:165)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readAnnotationValues(ClassReader.java:1491)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readAnnotationValue(ClassReader.java:1569)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readAnnotationValues(ClassReader.java:1487)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readAnnotationValue(ClassReader.java:1655)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readAnnotationValues(ClassReader.java:1483)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:909)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:671)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:508)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.metadata.model.AbstractAnnotationReadingMetadataProvider.runAnnotationMetadataVisitor(AbstractAnnotationReadingMetadataProvider.java:137)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.metadata.model.AbstractAnnotationReadingMetadataProvider.getAnnotationMetadata(AbstractAnnotationReadingMetadataProvider.java:115)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.metadata.model.AbstractAnnotationReadingMetadataProvider.provideBeanMetadata(AbstractAnnotationReadingMetadataProvider.java:69)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.metadata.internal.model.BeanMetadataBuilderJob$1.run(BeanMetadataBuilderJob.java:198)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.metadata.internal.model.BeanMetadataBuilderJob.attachMetadataToBean(BeanMetadataBuilderJob.java:191)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.metadata.internal.model.BeanMetadataBuilderJob.attachMetadata(BeanMetadataBuilderJob.java:170)
at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.beans.core.metadata.internal.model.BeanMetadataBuilderJob.run(BeanMetadataBuilderJob.java:141)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Can anyone help about this?

My sts version is:

Version: 3.4.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 201310051614

and the following is my sts.ini settings:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-product
org.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
1024M
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms524m
-Xmx4000m
-XX:MaxPermSize=4000m
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.IEVersion=10001
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you file an issue for this at: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS and maybe attach a sample project that reproduces the issue? That would be great. Will take a look asap.